# connection is "horizontal" than top-down - what does it mean

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

> Dear Jesus, I agree with you that we are in 50/50% case. However, at
>   least until now, social media are more independent, and the connection
>   is "horizontal" than top-down. Finally the technology, especially
>   computerts and robotics will change the present society. The problem
>   is if it will be for good and not for bad.

Here what is meaning of connection is "horizontal" than top-down. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is saying that the relationship in social media is more "***peer to peer***", that anyone can connect with anyone else and the structure is not a "***hierarchy***" or "***tree***".

An example of the latter might be a message from the president of a company, where the message is disseminated to managers first and then to the workers.

Comment: If you don't mind can you tell me the meaning of landscape in this sentence `The political landscape has changed quite a bit in the last couple of decades.`

Comment: Please submit a new question that way other askers will be able to see your question. I will be happy to answer your question after you do. If you follow on with questions the way you have, it will not appear in searches.